# Как подключить GeoIP модуль в docker контейнере Nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, геолокация

В документации к [модулю ngx_http_geoip_module](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html) указано, что модуль не собирается по умолчанию.

Как его установить в контейнере Nginx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доступные динамические модули размещены внутри контейнера в папке `/etc/nginx/modules`.
Для подключения модуля GeoIP достаточно использовать в `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` директиву:

```
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;
```

Для работы модуля необходимы два файла с GeoIP базой. Пути к ним нужно указать в двух директивах:

```
http {
...
    geoip_country         /path/to/GeoIPCountry.dat;
    geoip_city            /path/to/GeoIPCity.dat;
...
}
```

К сожалению поставщик геоданных больше не поддерживает формат .dat, а новый формат .mmdb поддерживается модулем geoip2 только в подписке Nginx Plus.
Скачать файлы .dat можно например [тут](https://mailfud.org/geoip-legacy/).